# Slice long data with specifications in r

Tags: r, tidyverse, slice

If I have data that looks like this

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)
age<-c(12,14,15,16,12,13,14,14,16,17,19,12,13,14,15,16,18,20,21)
grade<-c('B','C','C','A','D','B','B','A','B','A','A','D','F','B','F','F','B','B','C')
data<-data.frame(id,age,grade)
```

Assuming that ID is each student (1:5) having their grades measured at different times, I want to see at WHAT AGE their SUBSEQUENT grade change happens after they obtained their first B.
For student 1, who got a B  at age 12, s/he got a C at age 14 which is straight-forward. For student 5, however, s/he first got a B at age 18, then s/he got a B again at 20, so the first grade change happened at 21, which is a C.

I thought slice would be the best option.

`data %>% group_by(id,grade) %>% slice(which.min(age))`

but I am not sure how to include the next few rows to capture the "age" in which the B turns into another grade (that is not B again).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(data)[, .SD[first(which((1:.N) > first(which(grade == "B")) &
           grade != "B"))], id]
```

gives

```
   id age grade
1:  1  14     C
2:  3  17     A
3:  5  21     C
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a solution using dplyr's lag function:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, age, grade) %>%
  mutate(tag = ifelse(grade == lag(grade), "Same Grade", "Different Grade"))
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(!(duplicated(grade) & grade == 'B') ) %>%
    slice(match('B', grade) + 1)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
#     id   age grade
#  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#1     1    14 C    
#2     3    17 A    
#3     5    21 C
```